# How to use "loop" parallel processing by using GCD (grand central Dispatch )

Tags: c++, grand-central-dispatch

I have programmed `C++` under visual studio environment. there to do parallel processing i used openMP but OS X isn't supporting for openMP so i like to move GCD Apple . By using GCD how do i optimise the following loop ( here i want to do the thing what openMP does by using apple GCD) please help me to do that. thank you for any advance.

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(j)
                    for(i = 1; i <= I; i++){
                        for(j = 1; j <= J; j++){
                            if(max(1, m-Alpha+i0) <= i && i <= min(m+Alpha+i0, I) && max(1, n-Alpha+j0) <= j && j <= min(n+Alpha+j0, J)){
                            //  cout << i << ", " << j << endl;
                                _AccmCalc(i, j, m, n);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: For starters, you can remove the pointless min/max and change the for loops to iterate only through the indices that you are actually interested in.

Comment: @gnasher729 can you post it as answer then i can check you dude. tx for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can post multiple functions that are independent of each other and has no impact on their their result in the order they are executed into GCD dispatch and execute it asynchronously. Here is an example code, this is one of the way to optimize a for loop that executes do_work 'count' number of times:

```
dispatch_apply(count, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^(size_t i){
 results[i] = do_work(data, i);
});
```

src: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find a solution to this, and this is the first search result that comes up, I eventually figured it out and I'm posting the code here to help others who might stumble on this question.

With GCD as with OpenMP you parallelize the outer loop, here though the outer loop becomes a call to dispatch_apply, see Apple documentation for details on it.

```
dispatch_queue_t c_queue = dispatch_queue_create("myConcurrentQueue",
                                               DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
dispatch_apply(I, c_queue, ^(size_t i){
    size_t i2 = i + 1; // because in GCD i is [0, I) and we need [1, I]
    for(j = 1; j <= J; j++){
        if(max(1, m-Alpha+i0) <= i2 && i2 <= min(m+Alpha+i0, I) && max(1, n-Alpha+j0) <= j && j <= min(n+Alpha+j0, J)){
             //  cout << i2 << ", " << j << endl;
            _AccmCalc(i2, j, m, n);
        }
    }
});
```